# Maui Hybrid on Android install but not Open

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, maui

I have an app in Maui Blazor Hybrid, which launched from VS works correctly, but when I generate an apk and install it manually, it installs but does not open the app.

How can I see the error or do a debug in release mode.

Comment: Have you tried deploying directly to the device from VS or you use your device as emulator? Also it's the android version compatible?

Comment: Correct, I can launch it on the device from VS and it works, but when I generate an apk, I can install it, but it crashes when opening. 
Thanks Lenadro

Comment: Right click on your project -> view archives -> select the one you create -> distribute -> (select a hoc) -> select or create an identity -> and then open the folder and try to install the last Signed-apk (with the biggest size)

Comment: I did all the steps and it still has the same error, it does not show any information about the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use App Center Crashes to diagnose the error. It will automatically generate a crash log every time your app crashes. For more details, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/crashes/xamarin)

Comment: install the stable version of Visual Studio 17.3.4 for Windows and all the problems are gone